# CSS responsive issue in firefox before 768px

Tags: html, css

I use Meta tag inside head

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

Responsive css

In firefox even when the viewport width is 768px it is going to 767px media query can you please help me with it

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
   header{position: fixed;top: 0px;width: 100%;background: #fff;z-index: 9999;}
}
```

[Check this Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L58t3tts/2/)

It works perfectly in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: need an example to help you

Comment: How do you check this? using responsive view or by shrinking the window? maybe it is scrollbar ?!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: try using <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.8, zoom=10%, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=high-dpi">

Comment: Its not working.. Any other solutions???